# How can make this triangle?

Tags: r

[image]

[image]

I can make this triangle but, I can't make a blank.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
for (i in 1:h) {
  for (j in 1:h) {
    cat(replicate(h*(i-1)+1, ""))
    for (k in 1:j) {
      cat("*")
    }
    cat("\n")
  }
}
```

So at the start of every line within a triangle I added a replicate function that replicates an empty string h*(i-1)+1 times. The h*(i-1) is because you want to add an empty triangle of length h i-1 times in front of the actual triangle. The +1 is just a correction, I cannot exactly explain why it needs to be there but you will see the difference in results if you remove it. Some results:

h <- 4

```
*
**
***
****
    *
    **
    ***
    ****
        *
        **
        ***
        ****
            *
            **
            ***
            ****
```

h <- 2

```
*
**
  *
  **
```

small tip: unless strictly necessary don't use the same variable in multiple for statements. I changed the layout to i, j, k for you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try `strrep` within nested `for` loops like below

```
k <- 5
n <- 3
for (k in 1:k) {
  u <- strrep(" ",n*(k-1))
  for (i in 1:n) {
    v <- strrep("*",i)
    cat(paste0(u,v,"\n"))
  }
}
```

which gives

```
*
**
***
   *
   **
   ***
      *
      **
      ***
         *
         **
         ***
            *
            **
            ***
```